# fs.readFile returning string but with white space between every character and adding characters

Tags: node.js, readfile, fs

fs.readFile() returning string with whitespaces between every character and is also adding a tilde symbol as well(~)
this is transformed `<ApiDocument>`
into this `"~< A p i D o c u m e n t >"`

I was trying to parse XML to just get a string from a stored file. I thought I had maybe messed up in the file. so i created another file with just simple text in it like "test" and im getting the same symptoms "t e s t"

I also thought maybe it was because it was an xml file so i switched it to TXT and still got the same thing.

I dont seem to know how to articulate the problem because noone online seems to be having the same issue.

I also tried different encodings.

I am using Node version 10.15.0

```
fs.readFile("SalesReceiptExport.xml","UTF-8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);

});
```

I expect it to read the file that contains `<Apidocument>`
and return string with `"<ApiDocument>"`
but instead it transforms into `"~ < A p i D o c u m e n t>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the file written as Unicode? What happens if you do the following:

```
fs.readFile("SalesReceiptExport.xml","UTF-16", function(err,data) { 
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(data);
});
```

When the file is created, did you, or can you specify an encoding scheme?

Comment: It was when the file was being created. I didnt realize that was an issue. Thank you so much ive been getting so frustrated. Im not sure how the file i was being sent was just in UNICODE encoding apparently but ill look into it. The UTF-16 didnt work for me but it would have had the encoding been correct so thanks again.

Comment: It worked for me for a CSV generated with MS Teams. 
*Note*: I used `'utf16le'` rather than `UTF-16`

Comment: It worked for me with a file generated from a Delta DOP-100 HMI (industrial touch screen). Im using node-red and I had the same problem with spaces betweek letters and extra characters. Changing the encoding (on the read file node) to utf-16le solved it.